# How do I delete project in intelliJ IDEA 10.5?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project

I have created a project in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5, but it is very difficult to delete it. The project manager in Eclipse is much better than IntelliJ IDEA.

Can anybody explain to me how to do it from IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To remove a project in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5, close IDEA and delete the project directory.

---

As @Sheidaei mentioned in the comments, this does not work for IntelliJ IDEA 12. For deleting projects in IntelliJ 12, see the question which Christian Junk kindly pointed out: [How to delete projects in IntelliJ 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570743/how-to-delete-projects-in-intellij-12)

Comment: After deleting the directory, it still shows in recent projects in intellij 12, any ideas?

Comment: @sheidaei: For IntelliJ 12 please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570743/how-to-delete-projects-in-intellij-12

Comment: @ChristianJunk Sheidaei is actually the person who asked that question. But no worries! Thank you for the link, which I've incorporated into the answer, just in case another person like Sheidaei comes across this question and doesn't know where to go!

Answer (score 7):

Delete the `.idea` folder, and the `projectName.iml` file, both in the project directory.

Comment: where are they situated?I means path to the file?

Comment: @user1092450 Wherever you told IntelliJ to keep the project files, by default in the directory where all the files are, or wherever you specified if you overrode the default.

Comment: @Dave It's difficult when you have a project with 20+ sub-modules, each of which has a *.iml file.

Comment: @devdanke Why? `find` is your friend, it's like a 40 character command.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured, I am using Idea Community edition 13.1.1 and the cleanest and easiest way is to go to **File > Reopen project > Clear List**. I just stumbled upon this menu today. I always thought that is just to clear the latest projects from the view inside the IDE and just realized it is clearing the projects from the main Dialog too.