# New to intellij Idea 12.0.2, How do I delete projects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do I delete projects from the IDEA list. Also, can someone please tell me the pros on using IntelliJ so maybe I can talk some of the Eclipse users into using this product too?

Comment: Which list of projects are you asking about - the `File -> Reopen` list?

Comment: Pros?  IntelliJ IDE is the best Java IDE on the market.  It understands Java, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, Spring in a way that will feel like it's reading your mind after a while.  Eclipse is a Frankenstein monster made of disparate plug-ins.

Comment: In terms of features I would look at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/index.html

Comment: If you can't tell the pros of IntelliJ yourself, why would you want to talk others into it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first part of your question is a duplicate of several different posts, such as [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465875/how-do-i-delete-project-in-intellij-idea-10-5) 
 You may also want to refer to the [intellij help system for assistance.](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/intellij-idea.html)

The second part of your question is extremely subjective as each programmer has different wants/needs/desires with an IDE. However, for what its worth, take a look at the following:

- [How is intellij better then eclipse (programmers.stackexchange.com)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21987/how-is-intellij-better-than-eclipse)
- [Intellij vs Eclipse (codegeeks)](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/intellij-vs-eclipse.html)
- [A blog post](http://caffeinbean.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/a-sequel-to-netbeans-vs-eclipse-comparison-verdict-is-intellij/)
- [The JetBrains feature page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/?fromIndex)

There are lots of resources out there to look at for comparisons. However the best advise I've come across is: use it for two weeks, if it works for you then use it; if it doesn't then don't.