# How to delete projects in IntelliJ 12?

Tags: intellij-idea

I created some dummy projects. Now I don't see any way to delete the projects that I don't want. Per this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465875/how-do-i-delete-project-in-intellij-idea-10-5) I can delete files, the project is going away but there is traces of it still available. For example, on the Recent Projects you can still see the name of the project you just deleted. So I am thinking there should be another (and really easy way) to delete a project.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486326/new-to-intellij-idea-12-0-2-how-do-i-delete-projects/14486534#14486534

Comment: It is not duplicate, as I am only asking about deleting the project. The reference used in the one you linked is asking about intellij 10.5 where I am asking about intellij 12.0.

Answer (score 274, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Del</kbd> (or <kbd>fn</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd>) key to delete a project from the `Recent Projects` list.

[Vote for this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109052) to make it more obvious and user friendly.

Comment: I am using Mac to code, I tried delete key but it didn't have any effect on the list.

Comment: Tested on Mac with IDEA 12.0.2 and `Mac OS X` / `Mac OS X 10.5+` keymaps, [both work fine](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/Screenshots/4yx_fb3hgqpf.png) with `Delete` key.

Comment: for me was fn + delete key, not sure why though

Comment: For anyone who comes across this later (like me), note that you have to have focus on the IJ12 Recent Projects list (at least, in the window that opens if you have no project open). Clicking a project will focus the list, but also opens the project, which isn't useful for deleting it. I found you can use Tab to bring the list into focus.

Comment: For this Mac user, the Forward-Delete key works but not the common Delete key.

Comment: Talk about usability failure

Comment: I just tried this and found that neither `delete` nor `fn` + `delete` works, but the forward-delete key (that isn't on my laptop's keyboard) does the trick.

Comment: Where is the delete key in mac anyway? For me FN + Backspace worked.

Comment: Amusingly, I just accidentally discovered that Backspace works on Ubuntu too. On OSX, isn't Backspace the same as the Delete key for the rest of the world? I'm surprised you'd need to use an Fn key combo...

Comment: Thank you @ajp15243 I couldn't get it to delete either, I tabbed to the project as you suggested and it worked, what happened to just having the x button next to the project?

Comment: @alsobubbly I could swear I had an X at the top-right of each project in IntelliJ 14. I just updated yesterday to 14.1.4, and I don't see it. :/

Comment: Using delete can remove the project appearing on the project list, but the actually project files are still in the project directory. I have to rm -r to delete the project directory.

Answer (score 14):

close project first, or until this dialog appear, then hover your mouse on project you want to delete from history, then press `Del`
[image: main dialog]

you'll be asked for confirmation

[image: confirm]

Answer (score 9):

On occasion, even with deletion of the project, some tidbits are left behind in the following Windows paths:

- C:\Users\username.domain\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\compiler
- C:\Users\username.domain\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\compile-server
- C:\Users\username.domain\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\frameworks\detection
- C:\Users\username.domain\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\conversion
- C:\Users\username.domain\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\config\componentVersions
- C:\Users\username.domain\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\config\tasks

This has been proven to be problematic - for example, if a new project is created using a previously deleted project name, it will create the project with data stored in the above paths, at least, this has been my experience.

The only way to TRULY delete the project is to get rid of all the garbage left behind in the aforementioned folders. I would suggest using Search Everything to find more tidbits left in the users temp folders.

Comment: Given that creating a project with the same name is not rare in practice, this is so frustrating. PS: I'm using android studio which is based on it, this problem exist too.

Comment: Did any one find solution ? As after deleting project as described in most voted solution, entries of it still persists at the paths given above which really causes problems, when you will create project with same name.

Comment: Do you know where these "tidbits" are stored on Mac?

Comment: The "tidbits" are stored in the following location on a Mac:
 ~/Library/Caches/IntellijIdea<version>/compiler
 ~/Library/Caches/IntellijIdea<version>/frameworkds/detection
 ~/Library/Caches/IntellijIdea<version>/conversion
 ~/Library/Caches/IntellijIdea<version>/compile-server

Answer (score 3):

In case your project is imported as a module, you can also go to File --> Project Structure and click 'Modules' in the left section. Now you can hit the minus button to remote the module from the project.

Answer (score 3):

You can also click File -> Open project ...

When a file menu appears, you can right click the unwanted project folder and select Delete.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured, I am using Idea Community edition 13.1.1 and the cleanest and easiest way is to go to **File > Reopen project > Clear List**. I just stumbled upon this menu today. I always thought that is just to clear the latest projects from the view inside the IDE and just realized it is clearing the projects from the main Dialog too.

-VRS

Answer (score 2):

Also, in IDEA 13.x.x you can go `File-> Close Project` and you'll land in the window with `Recent Projects` tab. There pressing `Del` of `Fn + Del` on selected project helps .

Answer (score 1):

On OSX Mountain Lion and IDEA 14, with the project open and focused, you can go to **file -> close project**, then delete the project from your filesystem.  This removed all references to the project.

Note that if the project you are deleting is the only project open, closing it will show the welcome dialog, which will still show the project.  Deleting the project manually from within your operating system is the next step, and the project will still appear in the welcome dialog until it is closed and shown again, usually by opening another project from the list, or quitting and restarting IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to delete `home/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/config/options/recentProjects.xml`
. In my file system (Ubuntu) this file appeared for some weird reason not writable and hold a list of projects I couldn't get rid of. Deleting this file and restarting will force Intellij IDEA to create a new one with an empty list of projects.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is go to file - close project - to avoid seeing them again in the menu list and then you delete them from the projects directory.